# Triparting a Garden

Tags: visual, geometry

[image: garden]

A gardener wants to trisect his rectangular garden into three parts, with the proviso that he can neither enter on the left and leave on the right **AND** nor can he enter at the top and leave at the bottom.

> But he can't seem to do it! Can you?

Comment: Do the 3 parts need to be equal in area?

Comment: No, that's just my picture!

Comment: To clarify: will the farmer walk through one of the three green sections without crossing the black lines, or will he walk along the black lines without stepping into the green?

Comment: The lines in my picture are the walls, and the gardener can go from left to right in the bottom garden.

Comment: I _believe_ I have a proof that this is impossible, if I correctly understand what you are asking. Are you sure that there is a solution?

Comment: @ZanyG; I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect

> that this is impossible.

Reasoning:

> Each of the four corners must belong to one of the three sections. By the pigeonhole principle, at least one section must own at least two corners, and since that section is a traversable region, there exists a path between those two corners. However, this is disallowed, since it will traverse either the entire horizontal length or vertical with (or both) of the field. The trisection is thus impossible.

Comment: Exactly what I got!

Answer (score 13):

Why not?

> If he trisects the garden like a [flag of the Czech republic (depicted below)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_Czech_Republic) (by color), all conditions will be satisfied (note that white-blue and red-blue borders go *exactly* to the corners).
>  [image]

Comment: Right on the left border, or left to right of the top and base seem to contradict that.

Comment: @JMP What do you mean?

Comment: You can go from top-left to right in the white region for example.

Comment: @JMP The border goes **right** to the corner. So, the left side is all-blue (no access from white), and the top side is all-white (no access from blue).

Comment: Then you've got a footpath through the blue garden. And if the bottom left corner is red, you have a footpath through the red garden.

Comment: @JMP Corners are the points on the border, so they are neither blue nor red or white.

Comment: @JMP Does that mean you consider the divisions to be *footpaths* rather than *walls*?

Comment: @Stiv Yes, the question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @Stiv; no. the lines in my picture are walls.

Comment: @trolley813; you can also argue that they are **both** blue and red. Or that every point in the garden must be one of three colours.

Comment: ^ @JMP But that would assume your wall has no thickness at all. In reality it will be a number of bricks wide - I have a few solutions that work in the same way as trolley813's when you can assume the wall separates the field entirely at corners, but I don't understand why this is invalid from the specification? Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv Actually even if the wall has zero thickness, the points under the wall belong to the no part of the garden.

Comment: 'The Wall' is actually a Dedekind cut.

Comment: @JMP that looks rather a lame riddle then. I see the geometry tag, but in the post you describe the problem as down to earth as conceivably  possible. Well, down to earth gardens have walls of appreciable thickness, same as the actual people who walk in the gardens.